# PC turned on everything is blue colored

Tags: graphics-card, display

When I turned on my pc it turned on with blue screen but I can see everything on background of blue color. It is like the blue color is trying to block the display.

I unplugged/plugged all connections on the computer, but nothing happened. Then I tested the VGA cable and monitor with a TV box. It's working perfectly. So what's the problem with my computer?

[image]

Comment: Can we have a photo? (By the way, [this is a CPU](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/AMD_Phenom_II_X4_840_%28HDX840WFK42GM%29_CPU-top_oblique_PNr%C2%B00373.jpg). You have a problem with a _computer_, not a CPU.)

Comment: Do you have software such as f.lux (https://justgetflux.com/) installed on your PC? It could also be a malware.

Comment: This looks like the graphics card is broken. I suggest fitting a new graphics card to the expansion slots.

Answer (score 1):

- to work around the damaged VGA output, use a [digital connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_connectors) (there are e.g. cables with a DVI plug on one end and HDMI on the other end, if PC and monitor don't have the same)
- or replace/add graphics card